# Install4J - SystemInfo.getPhysicalMemory() is returning 0

Tags: java, memory, action, install4j

As per the following documentation: https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/SystemInfo.html#getPhysicalMemory()

The function SystemInfo.getPhysicalMemory() in an Install4J action should return the total number in bytes of memory that is available in the current system. However, currently, it is returning 0 which the documentation states mean that the information is not available.

An example is given in one of their blog posts: https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2010/12/more-installation-options-with-install4j/

Has anyone seen/fixed this before? What is preventing Install4J from retrieving this information?

Answer (score 0):

This method tries to obtain the value by calling

```
com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize()
```

if the return value of `ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()` has the above type.

Failing that, it tries different strategies depending on the platform:

- on Windows it uses a native implementation that calls the Windows API
- on macOS, it tries to call `sysctl hw.memsize` and `sysctl hw.physmem` and returns the first non-zero value
- on Linux, it checks `"/proc/meminfo` and reads the `MemTotal` entry.

If none of this works, it returns 0.

Comment: Thank you for that breakdown, previously this command worked with our installer however recently it has started returning 0 for some users. Do you know anything that might have changed recently to cause this issue?

Comment: Nothing has changed in the implementation of this command for quite some time.